# Django. Не могу подтянуть страницу из базы данных

Tags: python, sql, django, sqlite

Есть код, который должен динамически подгрузить страницу из базы данных (он 100% рабочий, запрос к странице есть):

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from news.models import Articles

urlpatterns = [
    path("",
        ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:5],
        template_name="news/posts.html")),
    url("<Тут должен быть вызов к БД>",
        DetailView.as_view(model=Articles,
        template_name="news/post.html")),
]
```

Я хочу, чтобы при переходе на определённую страницу, путь менялся с `news/` на `news/test`, где `test` - это значение поля page_name в моей базе данных.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: 1.не вызов к бд. 2. `path('<page_name:slug>', ....` 3. если 2 не сработает - то `<slug:page_name>` или смотрите в доке `django` про `urls.py`, `urlpatterns`, `path`, `generic views` и тп

Comment: При использовании третьего варианта вылезает вот такая ошибка: Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Comment: значит 2й вариант.